# pass variable between main functions along different python scripts

Tags: python, variables, import

I want to pass the variable "le" which is declared inside the main function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

from the python file "one.py"

to the main function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

to the python file "two.py"

I've tried to insert:

1. `import one` in the header of two.py
2. `from one import le` in the header of two.py

However, the two.py file cannot import the "le" variable". I got this error: `cannot import name 'le' from 'one'`. Both one and two file are within the same local folder.

Code:

one.py

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        le=le+i

        exec(open('two.py').read())
```

two.py

```
from one import le

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(le)
```

The result should be:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: You don't show a main function. If you mean the block guarded by that condition, it's **not** run when the module is imported - that's the whole point - so anything defined there won't be accessible.

Comment: I've tried to define it as global outside that block and the use it inside the __name__ == "__main__" block but it is neither accessible. Any idea?

Comment: It's unclear what you're describing. Give a [mre].

Comment: Could you please explain why are you doing what you are doing in a way you are doing it?

Comment: please, tell me which is the most optimal way to do it. I want to execute two codes in a loop and modifying the values in both files simultaneously, however, the second file I cannot execute another for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if __name__ == "__main__":` is not a function. It is a check whether the script is run as the main script and not imported. So when you import `one.py`, everything inside its `if __name__ == "__main__":` block is ignored.

Get your variable `le` out from this `if` statement and `from one import le` should work.

Comment: Yes, it works as you suggested, but I need to use "le" inside the  'if __name__ == "__main__":' block in both files

Comment: Define it above the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Answer (score 0):

well you are defining that 'le' variable inside `if __name__=="__main__"` which will never get executed as it is not been running in `__main__`. You'll better understand this if you put else block in one.py and assign le to some other string and import it into two.py as from one import le...then you'll see the 'le' value which was assigned in else block but not in `'__main__'` block. What I mean is let's say I wrote the following in one.py

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    le='assigned in main block'
else:
    le='assigned in else block'
```

If u imported this in two.py as below

```
from one import le
 print(le)
```

you'll get an output as following:

output: assigned in else block